# Restart after installation of Ubuntu 16.04 gets stuck on Synchronising SCSI Cache

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation

[This is screen I get after I press restart now at the end of installation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uwhr.jpg)

It gets stuck at [sda] Synchronising SCSI Cache.

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop.

Laptop Specs -

- HP Pavilion Power Laptop 15
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @2.80GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- 1 TB HDD and 128 GB SSD

I'm trying to install it on my HDD with 70gb partition. Also, I have disabled Secure Boot.